# How to ensure my connection is secure to Google

Tags: https, web, security

Blogspot blogs are banned in Iran, they redirected to a page that says you can't access that site. But when I try to open a blog via HTTPS prefix I get this error:

[image]

This is certification detail:

[image]

If I click **"Procced anyway"** it goes to `https://www.google.com` with green certification icon. (Figure blow)

[image]

## Question

How to make sure this connection is secure(I'm using a public WiFi)? Because it's so weird that I'm redirecting to a `https://www.google.com/` instead of blog or even blocking alert page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this particular case, I get the same behavior (And my connection is safe).  Blogspot doesn't support HTTPS, so you're getting a certificate for another Google product, which is then dumping you back at the homepage because the cert and the site name don't match up.

If you're concerned about your traffic being intercepted, then I'd say use a VPN.

Comment: where are you connecting from?

Comment: @Mohsen I'm in the US and get the same error. I guess Google doesn't care about https blogging

Comment: USA.  About 20miles from Google HQ as it were.